# Anaconda Package Installation:Package missing in current win-32 channels

Tags: python, anaconda, pyml

I am trying to install `PyML-0.7.14` using anaconda.In anaconda prompt, I am giving

1. `conda install pyml-0.7.14`
2. `conda install pyml`
3. `conda install pyml=0.7.14`

Each of these is giving error:

> Package missing in current win-32 channels.

I have also tried installation using `pip`

4. `pip install pyml`

but it is giving:

> could not find a version that satisfies the requirement. PyML available on anaconda cloud is for 64 bit only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a version of PyML for 32 bit Python distributions.

You will need to install the 64 bit version of python to use PyML. You can find it at the [Anaconda Windows downloads](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows) page.

Furthermore it seems the current latest version of PyML on anaconda cloud is 0.2.2. It may be possible to install PyML from source following the [PyML tutorial](http://pyml.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html), but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Can i install it without anaconda ? Using Python Only.

Comment: The directions in the tutorial dont use Anaconda